# onchange to change text color inside contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a select box that has options of different colors, as well as a contenteditable inside a div to be used as a text editor. What I want is when I select a color from the box e.g. red, the selected text inside the contenteditable changes to red.

```
        <select id="colorChange">
            <option onchange="value="Black">Black</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Any issue with me asking a simple question? I'm new to javascript and html in general, what's wrong with asking a question on a forum that was intended to get people to do so anyways?

Comment: Yes, there's an issue, you haven't shown any effort you've put so far to solve your problem. Currently you have no question, rather it's a task requirement. Please do some [research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), and come back, if you'll get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Onchange of options call a function and use jquery `.css` method to the change the text color.

```
function changeColor(){
 var _color = $("#colorChange option:selected" ).val().toLowerCase();
$("#abc").css('color',_color)
}
```

Note: There is a  typo in `<option onchange="value="Black">Black</option>`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rr4c4htw/1/)

Comment: The typo's been changed, and I'll try out your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:)

```js
$('#colorChange').on('change', function() {
  $color = this.value 
  $("select option:selected").css("color", $color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="colorChange">
            <option onchange="value="Black">Black</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `jQuery` solution.

1. `onchange` needs to be on `select`.
2. Apply the selected color to the `div`.

```js
$(function() {
  var color = 'black';

  $('select').change(function() {
    color = $(this).val();
    $('div').css('color', color);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="colorChange">
  <option value="Black">Black</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div contenteditable="true">This text color will change based on selection</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the change event on the select input, grab its value then change the color of your container using CSS.

```
    $('#colorChange').change(function(){
       var selectedColor = this.value;
       $('#container').css('color', selectedColor);
    });
```

This method will work when using color names Supported by all browsers (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) if you want custom colors you will need to either set the value of the options in the select input to the HEX(#) value for the color required or pass selectedColour through a switch statement to determine the color code.

Comment: This is only a partial answer to the question. The question was: [How to get] "the __selected text__ inside the contenteditable [to change] to red."

Comment: $('#container').css('color', selectedColor); This part of the call back does what he is asking?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `#container` has nothing to do with a __selected text block__ in an editable `div`. Looks like all the answers are suffering more or less of the same problem, i.e. ignoring the "selected text" part.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript version. I really hope I am not doing your homework.

```
document.getElementById('colorChange').addEventListener('change',function(event){
   var val = event.target.value; 
   var div = document.getElementById('editableDiv'); 
   div.style.color = val;
});
```